# Independent vectors and linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

2. Let $L\colon (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7) \mapsto 2x_3 + 3x_4 + 8x_6 + x_7$: Is $L$ a linear map?
   If it is, how to find independent vectors in  $\operatorname{Ker}(L)$?

Comment: Would those voting to close please help the OP to improve their question?

Comment: @user1729: to a person with that user name? seriously?

Comment: I've noticed that you several questions today. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, stackexchange software will not allow you to do so.) For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Comment: @Martin Yeah, okay, but surely closing a question should be localised to the question? Names are a moderator issue, no?

Comment: @user1729 I don't know how to ping the other Martin in this discussion, see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4801/agent-smith-calling-agent-smith).

Comment: @Martin Gah!${}$

Answer (score 1):

(I assume $L$ goes from $\mathbb{R}^7$ to $\mathbb{R}$, for instance)

**Hint:** Try to write $L(\vec{x})$ as $\langle \vec{a}, \vec{x} \rangle = \sum_{k=1}^7 a_kx_k$ for some vector $\vec{a}\in\mathbb{R}^7$. $L$ is a linear map iff you can (if you don't see why, show it — it is always useful to know).

Then, if it is the case to find a basis (maximal set of independent vectors) in $\operatorname{Ker}L$, you first have to solve (for $\vec{x}=(x_k)_{1\leq k\leq 7}$) the equation $\sum_{k=1}^7 a_kx_k = 0$. Then,"skim" them to get a basis of the (now explicit) space of solutions.

Comment: can u work that out for me its seem comclicated for me . I am just a begginer.

Comment: Start by trying; if you can't get through, write what you did and where you are blocked.

Answer (score 1):

$L$ is linear:
$$
L(\alpha(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7) + \beta (y_1, y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5,y_6,y_7)) = L(\alpha x_1+\beta y_1,\dots,\alpha x_7 +\beta y_7 ) \\
$$
and
\begin{align*}
L(\alpha x_1+\beta y_1,\dots,\alpha x_7 +\beta y_7 )  &= 2(\alpha x_3 + \beta y_3) + 3(\alpha x_4+\beta y_4) + 8(\alpha x_6 + \beta y_6) + (\alpha x_7+\beta y_7)\\
& = \alpha(2x_1 + 3x_4 + 8x_6 +x_7) + \beta (2y_1 + 3y_4+8y_6+y_7) \\
&= \alpha L(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7) + \beta L(y_1, y_2,y_3,y_4,y_5,y_6,y_7)
\end{align*}

$$
Ker(L) = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7): 2x_3 + 3x_4+8x_6+x_7 = 0  \}
$$
or
$$
Ker(L) = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7): x_7 = -2x_3 - 3x_4 - 8x_6
  \}
$$
meaning that 
$$
Ker(L) =  \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,-2x_3 - 3x_4 - 8x_6); x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6 \in \mathbb{R}  \}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $L$ is a linear map. To prove it all you have to do is take $(x_1,...,x_7),(y_1,...,y_7)\in \Bbb R ^7, \lambda \in \Bbb R$ and prove $L(x_1+\lambda y_1,...,x_7+\lambda y_7)=L(x_1,...,x_7)+\lambda L(y_1,...,y_7)$.

$Ker(L)=\left\{(x_1,...,x_7)\in \Bbb R^7 \mid L(x_1,...,x_7)=0\right\}=\left\{(x_1,...,x_7)\in \Bbb R^7 \mid 2x_3+3x_4+8x_6+x_7=0\right\}=\left\{(x_1,...,x_7)\in \Bbb R^7 \mid x_7=-2x_3+-3x_4+-8x_6\right\}=\left\{(x_1,...,-2x_3+-3x_4+-8x_6) \mid (x_1,...,x_6)\in\Bbb R^6\right\}=\left\{x_1(1,0,0,0,0,0,0)+x_2(0,1,0,0,0,0,0)+x_3(0,0,1,0,0,0,-2)+x_4(0,0,0,1,0,0,-3)+x_5(0,0,0,0,1,0,0)+x_6(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,-8) \mid (x_1,...,x_6)\in\Bbb R^6\right\}$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the linearity condition for any application $L: V \to W$ between vector spaces $V$ and $W$ is that $L(\lambda x + y) = \lambda L(x) + L(y)$ for every $x,y\in V$. Now in your case we have $V = \mathbb{R}^7$ and $W=\mathbb{R}$ and $L$ is given by:

$$L(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7) = 2x_3 + 3x_4 + 8x_6 + x_7$$

Now, let's try to apply $L$ to some $\lambda x + y$ and see what happens. First, note that if we pick arbitrary $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^7$ they will be written in the form:

$$x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6, x_7)$$

$$y = (y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5, y_6, y_7)$$

In this case $\lambda x + y = (\lambda x_1 + y_1, \dots, \lambda x_7 + y_7)$ so that it's pretty obvious that we can write the following relation for the components $(\lambda x + y)_i = \lambda x_i + y_i$. Now let's apply $L$: note first what $L$ does, it takes the third component of the vector, multiplies by $2$, sum to the fourth component multiplied by $3$, sum to the sixth component multiplied by $8$ and sum to the seventh component alone.

Now, for the vector $(\lambda x + y)$ the $i$-th component is $(\lambda x + y)_i$ which I've already argumented what it is. So we have:

$$L(\lambda x + y) = 2(\lambda x + y)_3 + 3(\lambda x + y)_4 + 8 (\lambda x + y)_6 +(\lambda x + y)_7$$

Substituting we have:

$$L(\lambda x + y) = 2(\lambda x_3 + y_3) + 3(\lambda x_4 + y_4) + 8(\lambda x_6 + y_6) + (\lambda x_7 + y_7)$$

Now reorganize this putting in evidence $\lambda$:

$$L(\lambda x + y) = \lambda(2x_3 + 3x_4 + 8x_6 + x_7)+(2y_3 + 3y_4 + 8y_6 + y_7)$$

Now look inside the parentheses. There's $L(x)$ and $L(y)$, so that we have shown that we have the linearity condition holding $L(\lambda x + y) = \lambda L(x) + L(y)$.

To find the kernel, you impose $L(x) = 0$ and try to find what conditions are imposed over $x$. The set of all those $x$ is the kernel. So you'll have $2x_3 + 3x_4 + 8x_6 + x_7 = 0$, so to impose a condition, you isolate one of the $x_i$. I'll isolate $x_7$ because it has no coefficients, but you can choose another. We have:

$$x_7 = -2x_3 - 3x_4 - 8x_6$$

Now the solutions are obtained by allowing $x_1$ trough $x_6$ vary as they want, but with $x_7$ restricted to this. So to make this cleaner we set $x_i = \alpha_i$ for $i \neq 7$ and we set $x_7 = -2\alpha_3 - 3\alpha_4 - 8\alpha_6$, so that a general solution $x$ will be:

$$x = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4, \alpha_5, \alpha_6, -2\alpha_3 - 3\alpha_4 - 8\alpha_6)$$

So that you have $\ker L = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^7 : x = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4, \alpha_5, \alpha_6, -2\alpha_3 - 3\alpha_4 - 8\alpha_6), \alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}\}$

Comment: everything is now clear to me thank u  all of u guys